# Why does ActionEvent return 0 rather than calculated future compound interest from formula?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am trying to create a simple future compound interest application inside of a JFrame created in NetBeans. User is to type the Present Amount, Quarterly Rate, and amount of time in years into each JTextField within the JFrame. When the user clicks 'Calculate' Button the resultTextField should print the result. However, my program returns 0 regardless of numbers entered.

My guess is there is something i'm missing within this line of code:

```
private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {
    if(evt.getSource().equals(calculateButton))
{
   result =  compoundMethod(int1, int2, int3);
   resultTextField.setText(String.valueOf(result));

}
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem is here. Can someone help me out. Would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!!

```
package apppackage; //Declared in netbeans

public class interestGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public double int1 = 0;
public double int2 = 0;
public double int3 = 0;
public double result = 0;
/**
 * Creates new form interestGUI
 */
public interestGUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    amountTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    rateTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    periodsTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    AmountLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    RateLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    PeriodsLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    FormulaTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    resultTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    calculateButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    amountTextField.setText("0");
    amountTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            amountTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    rateTextField.setText("0");
    rateTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            rateTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    periodsTextField.setText("0");
    periodsTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            periodsTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    AmountLabel.setText("Amount");

    RateLabel.setText("Rate");

    PeriodsLabel.setText("Periods");

    FormulaTextField.setText("S = P ( 1 + i * t) ");
    FormulaTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            FormulaTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    resultTextField.setText("0");
    resultTextField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            resultTextFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("Future Value Formula");

    calculateButton.setText("Calculate");
    calculateButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            calculateButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Result:");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new        javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(172, 172, 172)
                    .addComponent(calculateButton))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(94, 94, 94)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                            .addComponent(resultTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(AmountLabel)
                                .addComponent(amountTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                                    .addComponent(RateLabel)
                                    .addGap(54, 54, 54))
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(rateTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 52, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGap(37, 37, 37)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(PeriodsLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(periodsTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(154, 154, 154)
                    .addComponent(FormulaTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(143, 143, 143)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(128, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(4, 4, 4)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(FormulaTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 34, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(AmountLabel)
                .addComponent(RateLabel)
                .addComponent(PeriodsLabel))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(amountTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(rateTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(periodsTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(calculateButton)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(resultTextField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2))
            .addGap(26, 26, 26))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>



 public double compoundMethod(double presentValue, 
         double interestRate, double totalInterestPeriods )
  {
double compoundBalance;
totalInterestPeriods = totalInterestPeriods*4;
interestRate = ((interestRate/100) / 4); // Compute interestRate (updated)
compoundBalance = presentValue*(Math.pow(1+interestRate,      totalInterestPeriods));


return compoundBalance;

 }



private void amountTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     {
int1 = Double.parseDouble(amountTextField.getText());
}

private void rateTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int2 =  Double.parseDouble(rateTextField.getText());
}

private void periodsTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int3 = Double.parseDouble(periodsTextField.getText());
}

private void FormulaTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getSource().equals(calculateButton))
{
   result =  compoundMethod(int1, int2, int3);
   resultTextField.setText(String.valueOf(result));

}
}

private void resultTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {
  resultTextField.setText(String.valueOf(result));
 }

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interestGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interestGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interestGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(interestGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the form
     */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new interestGUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JLabel AmountLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField FormulaTextField;
private javax.swing.JLabel PeriodsLabel;
private javax.swing.JLabel RateLabel;
private javax.swing.JTextField amountTextField;
private javax.swing.JButton calculateButton;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JTextField periodsTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField rateTextField;
private javax.swing.JTextField resultTextField;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: `interestRate = interestRate /= 4;` looks interesting...

Comment: compounded quarterly?

Comment: After doing a little bit of debugging, `int1`, `int2` and `int3` are `0`.  I suggest you place some `System.out.println` statements into you code and see what values you are using as well as try your hand at some debugging.  Also, as to my previous comment, you might like to do some research into "integer division" issues ;) (Not every user will press [Enter] on a text field ;))

Comment: I love Netbeans generated code!

Comment: @hfontanez I hate all form editors equally

Comment: Ahhh and so it is revealed!!!!!!! What is the solution to not requiring 'press [enter]'

Comment: interestRate = ((interestRate/100) / 4);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic problem comes down to a misunderstanding over how `ActionEvent`s are generated by `JTextField`s.

Essentially, they are generated (typically) when the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  This means, that if you never press <kbd>Enter</kbd> while the fields have focus, the values `int1`, `int2` and `int3` are `0`

Instead, when the user presses the <kbd>Calculate</kbd> button, grab the values from the fields then

```
private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource().equals(calculateButton)) {
        int1 = Double.parseDouble(amountTextField.getText());
        int2 = Double.parseDouble(rateTextField.getText());
        int3 = Double.parseDouble(periodsTextField.getText());
        result = compoundMethod(int1, int2, int3);
        resultTextField.setText(String.valueOf(result));

    }
}
```

I would also encourage you to have a look at using `JSpinner` or `JFormattedTextField`'s which are capable of managing numerical values much better then `JTextField`

Have a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more details

Comment: I was going to make the suggestion of using `JFormattedTextField`. It is a much simpler way to avoid problems with invalid numeric strings.